# Coq: viewing proof term during proof script writing

Tags: coq, dependent-type, termination, theorem-proving, ltac

So, I've got a proof that looks like this:

```
induction t; intros; inversion H ; crush.
```

It solves all my goals, but when I do `Qed`, I get the following error:

`Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix.`

So somewhere in the generated proof term, there's non-well-founded recursion. The problem is, I have no idea where.

Is there a way to debug this kind of error, or to see the (possibly non halting) proof term that the tactics script generates?

Comment: Note that you can write `{struct n}` to tell Coq that the decreasing argument should be `n`, and thereby get a better error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Show Proof.` to view the proof term so far.

Another command that can help with seeing where the recursion went wrong is `Guarded.`, which runs the termination checker on the proof term so far. You'll need to break apart the tactic script into independent sentences to use it, though. Here's an example:

```
Fixpoint f (n:nat) :  nat.
Proof.
  apply plus.
  exact (f n).
  Guarded.
(* fails with:
   Error:
   Recursive definition of f is ill-formed.
   ...
 *)
Defined.
```

Comment: Does `Guarded` work when Coq cannot guess the decreasing argument of fix?

Comment: It turns out when you define a Fixpoint in proof mode, Coq always uses the last argument as the decreasing argument (and if it's not inductive, the command just fails). Then `Guarded` ensures that this argument is decreased. Note that you can always explicitly provide a `{struct n}` annotation at definition time, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Show Proof.` command inside proof mode to print the proof term produced so far.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other excellent answers, I also want to point out that using `induction` inside an interactive-mode `Fixpoint` is usually a mistake, because you're recursing twice.  Writing fixpoints in interactive mode is often tricky because most automation tools will happily make a recursive call at every possible opportunity, even when it would be ill-founded.

I would advise to use `Definition` instead of `Fixpoint` and use `induction` in the proof script.  This invokes the explicit recursor, which allows for much better control of automation.  The disadvantage is decreased flexibility since fixpoints have fewer restrictions than recursors - but as we've seen, that is both a blessing and a curse.

Comment: If you are very careful, using `induction` inside of a `Fixpoint` is a relatively easy way to prove things about functions which contain nested fixpoints.  You have to make sure to specialize the fixpoint before running anything like `auto`, though.

Comment: @JasonGross That's reasonable, though I would also consider abstracting the necessary nested induction into its own scheme so that there's no need to be so careful.